# How to declare a inline object with inline variables without a parent class

Tags: c#

I am trying to do something like:

```
Object [] x = new Object[2];

x[0]=new Object(){firstName="john";lastName="walter"};
x[1]=new Object(){brand="BMW"};
```

I want to know if there is a way to achieve that inline declaration  in C#

Answer (score 124, accepted):

yes, there is:

```
object[] x = new object[2];

x[0] = new { firstName = "john", lastName = "walter" };
x[1] = new { brand = "BMW" };
```

you were practically there, just the [declaration of the anonymous types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) was a little off.

Comment: @hunter, BUT, how can I access the object variables later without the object being a "var". I can't do x[1].brand.

Comment: anonymous types are...anonymous - you can only use them with var, or in C# 4 with `dynamic` types, otherwise you will have to create a class instance, which works the same way, just add the class name after `new` and have the class expose the appropriate public properties

Comment: edit: I forgot to mention I am trying to do that in a Dictionary<string,Object>

Comment: If you're using C# 4.0, you might be able to use the "dynamic" keyword to accomplish what you want. Otherwise, you'll probably need to use a Dictionary<string, string> instead. Historically, C# has not been very good with the sort of dynamic typing you're attempting.

Comment: @deadlock unless your data is completely random I would suggest creating some classes. Even using `vars` within the context of your `object[]` won't be reference-able from outside of this scope.

Comment: @hunter, I did so and it still will not let me access the objects member. Please check that more specialized question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709472/dictionarystring-object-will-not-let-me-access-the-object-members

Comment: how can I declare object methods?

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this:

```
var x = new object[] {
    new { firstName = "john", lastName = "walter" },
    new { brand = "BMW" }
};
```

And if they are the same anonymous type (firstName and lastName), you won't need to cast as `object`.

```
var y = new [] {
    new { firstName = "john", lastName = "walter" },
    new { firstName = "jill", lastName = "white" }
};
```

Comment: Clearly the more better modern answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can also declare 'x' with the keyword var:

```
var x = new
{
  driver = new
  {
    firstName = "john",
    lastName = "walter"
  },
  car = new
  {
    brand = "BMW"
  }
};
```

This will allow you to declare your x object inline, but you will have to name your 2 anonymous objects, in order to access them. You can have an array of "x" :

```
x.driver.firstName // "john"
x.car.brand // "BMW"

var y = new[] { x, x, x, x };
y[1].car.brand; // "BMW"
```