# Dictionary<string,Object> will not let me access the Object members

Tags: c#

Considering:

```
Dictionary<string,Object> dict = new Dictionary<string,Object>();

dict.Add("Name","deadlock");
dict.Add("Birthday",new BD(12,12,1955));
```

Knowing that BD is:

```
public class BD {

public int Day {get; set; }
public int Month {get; set; }
public int Year {get; set;}

public BD(int x,int y,int z) { Day=x; Month=y; Year=z; }
}
```

My problem is that I can't reference Day,Month,Year from the dictionary like that:

```
int Day1 = dict["Birthday"].Day;
```

The above code won't work. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Yes, why are you using a Dictionary to store string types, and BD types?

Comment: You should make a `Dictionary<string, DateTime>`.

Comment: @Shan, it doesn't store string types. string is the data type of the Dictionary key.

Comment: @deadlock - it stores strings as the key, Object as the value. This line: dict.Add("Name","deadlock"); means that you're storing strings as the value, in addition to BD types as the value. Any reason why?

Comment: @deadlock, no @shan is right. The first item with key "Name" you are storing "Deadlock" which is a string. Why are you doing this? It's almost as if you are using a Dictionary to approximate a class.

Comment: @Shan, Because I am trying to make it dynamic. I need a dictionary to contain values of strings,objects,ints that can be referenced with a key of type string. eg: "Name","Birthday". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @deadlock, I don't know if you're doing anything wrong since I don't know the goal of your program. But gut feeling is you're doing something wrong, it seems an unnatural thing to use a polymorphic Dictionary, these days. Are you trying to look up people and their birthdates by some type of key?

Comment: No I am creating an Array of dictionaries. Each dictionary in the array should be like a settings object for a thread. The thread should be able to access many settings through that dictionary. The settings datatypes vary accordingly. for example, "thread-id"-> int; "thread-name"->string; "Downloader-Object"-> Downloader(); and so on. that's why I did Dictionary<string,Object>

Comment: Ok...sounds like a strongly-typed settings class may fit your need better than doing all sorts of run-time type casting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int Day1 = ((BD)dict["Birthday"]).Day;
```

You need to cast it into a BD object.

Comment: I tried that before asking the question. I just missed the outer brackets that's why it didn't work. It's working now thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the object to the type you want to use:

```
int Day1 = ((BD) dict["Birthday"]).Day;
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `dict["Birthday"]` returns an Object of type `Object`

In order to use this as expected, you need to cast the object to an appropriate type.

```
if(dict["Birthday"] is BD)
{
  var bd = dict["Birthday"];
  bd.Day; //do something useful
}

//or
var bd = dict["Birthday"] as BD
if(bd != null)
{
  bd.Day; //something useful
}
```

However, what you are doing is a kludge. Collections are most effective when storing homogeneous types. By storing generic objects, you can certainly store mixed types, but you have the added responsibility of ensuring type safety before casting.

Answer (score 1):

Although multiple data types are always in play on a variable or reference, the instance members are filtered through the eyes of only one data type (and what it inherited). Therefore the stated (declared) data type at a time.  Then the compiler knows what data type of multiple it is dealing with at that point.

In your case any instance of BD is all of the types: `BD` and `System.Object` through inheritance. If any interfaces had been implemented then those would be additional data types that the instance is also.

However type `Object` only shows Object members (and what it inherited, which is nothing more) even if the data type `BD` is also part of it.

To explicitly state to the C# compiler your intention of what data type to use of multiple available, you will have to "downcast", cast and/or convert accordingly using one of the mechanisms in C#/.NET like: C# casting `((BD)dict["Birthday"]).Day;`, explicit conversion between compatible reference types `(dict["Birthday"] as BD).Day;`. In the case of basic data types you can also use conversion e.g. `System.Convert.ToInt32(myLongValue)`. More features exist in .NET to support conversion endeavours.